# IntelliJ IDEA: Searching among opened files

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Sometimes we need the searching among *opened files* in **IntelliJ IDEA**.
For example: `class="redtext"`
Usually I have a large number of opened files and the manual searching takes a lot of time (**Ctrl+F** in every *html-file*).

Is there a *faster way* to do this?

Comment: In Intellij IDEA 2017, Use Ctrl+Shift+F-> Select Scope-> Select Open Files for your search term.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Under **scope** you can select **custom** and **Open files**:

[image: screenshot]